# Human-Machine Readable - Structured Data Storage in files

Tags: python, xml, ubuntu

I need to store structured file data that is both human and machine readable.    I mainly use python to open/edit/read these files.   However I may need to use other programs as well.

I used to use XML/XPATH.  However, the xpath libraries are frail and don't work on most systems withtout a significant amount of frustration. I am tired trying to figure out xpath this I port my scripts to different platform.

```
 me@ubuntu:~/$ program -arg1 "foo" -arg2
   File "/home/me/bin/script.py", line 16, in <module>
     from xml import xpath 
 ImportError: cannot import name xpath
```

BTW, `sudo apt-get install python-xml` does not fix this problem.

The bottom line is that I am fed up with xml/xpath.  I want a solution that will work in all cases, on all platforms, without question!

What can I use? Advice?

Comment: What are you using it for? XPath/XQuery are a VERY powerful means of querying nested data, and are arguably the most supported across platforms. JSON doesn't have nearly as robust a query language defined yet, but if you just need simple querying, it has very wide platform support. YAML is an even simpler alternative; more human readable, but not as suitable for complex nested data like JSON/XML.

Answer (score 1):

[`xml.etree.elementTree`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is part of the standard library since Python 2.5. It also contains a basic XPath [`findall`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall) function.

Alternatively, you can [lxml's XPath methods](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath) which mimic the interface of `xml.etree.ElementTree`, but support more advanced XPath expressions. However, lxml needs to be [installed](http://lxml.de/installation.html) as it is not (yet) part of the standard library.

For many tasks, you can also use [JSON](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) instead of XML. JSON is easy to parse and traverse with the native functions of your programming language.